# How to stich byteArrays with sound seamless together in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, arrays

I have loaded mp3 files and I've extracted the byte array.
i can play the byte array, but when I want to change byte array I hear a little glitch.

if I load the original wave files into flash and play them on timeline, there is no glitch, but if I get the wave files from library (witch will then be mp3s) they still glitch when going from one byte array to another in as3..

does anyone know how to solve this?

this is the code I use when reading a byte array

```
public function getSoundData():ByteArray{
        mixBytes.position = 0;



        // IF no sounds, plsy silent note
        if (activeSounds.length==0) {

            trace("no sound", silentSound.position, totalTime);

            for (var k:int=0;k< 4096; k++) {

                if(silentSound.position < totalTime){
                    mixBytes.writeFloat(silentSound.readFloat());
                    partPosition = silentSound.position;
                }else{
                    p.gotoNextSequence();
                    reset();    
                    return mixBytes;
                }

                //partPosition++;
            }
            trace("s", mixBytes.length);
            return mixBytes;
        } // sanity check

        // ELSE IF ANY SOUND
        // GET MIX THE VALUES
        var mixrate:Number=1.0/activeSounds.length;
        for (var i:int=0;i< BUFFER_SIZE;i++) { // adjust number accordingly
            var tm:int=0; // how many tracks mixed
            var f:Number=0;

            for each(var b:ByteArray in activeSounds){
                b.position = partPosition;
                if (b.position < b.length) {
                    // this track isn't finished
                    tm++; 
                    f+=b.readFloat();
            //      trace(b.length);
                    partPosition = b.position;
                }
            }

            if (tm==0) { // all tracks reached end, stop mixing
                trace("done mixing now!");                  
                p.gotoNextSequence();
                reset();    
                return mixBytes;
            }
            mixBytes.writeFloat(f*mixrate);
        }

        trace("l", mixBytes.length);
        return mixBytes;
    }
```

EDIT:

I have an array with soundParts, this code above is in an soundPart.
on when the Sound object need more data i run the this code:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = completeSong[sequenceNumberActiv].getSoundData();
        bytes.position = 0;

        while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0) { 
            e.data.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat()); 
            e.data.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat()); 
        }
```

and when that sound part is done, I update the variable **sequenceNumberActiv** so it gets bytes from the next sound part.

and I don't think it is delay by changing array that does it, cause I've tried to write two sound parts to one byte array and loop through that and there is still a glich.

I did though import the wav to flash and set compression to raw. that seemed to fix the issue. but I have hundreds of music files so I need then to work with mp3.

the mp3 I import have no fade in or out when i check them in audition, but it have more bytes than the raw sound file...

so I have tried to remove the start and end of the byte array with mixed luck, and no consistency there.. so I'm it works, but not good enough I think. any thoughts on this would really help :)

Comment: where in the code you go from one ByteArray to another? You only have one mixing buffer.

Comment: it looks like this (partPosition = b.position;) is causing the position to increment before it looks at the next sound's bytes... so it would read float 0 for sound 0, float 1 for sound 1, etc.  so you are getting sample from each sound that are a "hair" off.  Try updating partPosition after the for loop and see if that fixes it maybe.

Comment: actually thinking about it a little more, you shouldn't even need the partPosition var.  All of their positions should be equal as you loop and read.  Maybe just if(b.bytesAvailable > 0) f += b.readFloat();

Comment: Thanks for all the answer! the partPosition is a variable i use to save the position of this soundPart. The reason for that is because the user can change the sound at any time and to keep it in sync with the current timeline i set the position of the new byte array to that saved position. if I don't, it will start to play this clip from position one

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko thanks for the reply, I updated the question, does it make any sense? :)

Comment: @JasonReeves I don't use the partPosition other when I change the byte array, but I should just set partPosition before I change and not on update like now.

Comment: I was going to advice to use a raw format. It looks like mp3 compression issue. At least, use the best possible quality CBR-320 compression. Also, I don't know why you're using Floats. There are no Floats in a sound data, only integers.

Comment: it is now 24mb in with mp3, that would be nearer 240mb in raw...
so i wil have to make this work with mp3, the sounds are all all divided in 5 different lengths, and all sounds in the different parts are the same length, so if I cant find an universal solution, I might have to hack it to work.. but I really don't want to do that :)

Comment: I'd like to help you if you send me the working example. I need to hear how it sounds.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko, thanks, i'll see if I can make an simple example

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko you can download a zip with an example here:
http://www.thomasnordahl.no/gruff/flash.zip

Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko the reason it sounds nice between section 0 and 1 is because of this hack

**s.extract( bytes, 44100 * (s.length/1000) - 4096);**

I thought i found the secret "make it all work" hack, but if you listen to between sequence 1 and 2, it doesn't work..

Comment: I cannot open fla file as it was created with Flash CC and I have Flash CS6. I'll try to use the source files to rewrite the project.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko the fla is empty but has StichTest as main class
in library I have a movie clip with linkage to player.MusicPlayer. :)

Comment: Thank you, I built it in FlashDevelop and it works. However I need some extra time to learn the code and test various things. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Speaking the "modtracker" terminology, there are instruments as separate notes, organized in patterns. In your player, you have only patterns, recorded as complete music chunks, so here is a question: is it necessary to mix them programmatically? As far as I can see, you can just play patterns in different sound channels.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I am making I a kind of mixer, where you have a song on ca 30 seconds that that is devided in 5 different parts. the song is also devided up in tracks of instruments so you can choose to have guitar, piano and drums. and all of these instruments witch is devided up in 5 parts of the song can change genre, like polka, reggae and hip hop.

now additionally to this you can add predefined vocals (that is not divided up, but are one chunk on 30 sec) and you can record your own voice... 

all of this are mixed realtime and at the end you can save it all as an mp3

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko The solution was to load mp3 that was not chopped up, but rather do that in as3, I might try to load chopped up mp3s later, as I use some time now to process the mp3s. But the result is gapless, so for now I'm satisfied. Thanks for looking into it anyways :)
You can see the result here: http://gruffify.no , Click the Green button (lag låt)

Comment: Oh, good! Sorry, I was going to deal with it but got too much work pressing :( Will comment here if I find other solution, anyway.